# integer overflow in below program for max int 1000 000(which is under range of int)

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem on spoj,[SPOJ CARDS](https://www.spoj.com/problems/CRDS/)
The problem is easy and i am getting correct output for small numbers,But it seems to spoj is not accepting due to integer overflow ,
Then what integer type should i use?

OR is there any other problem that they are not accepting it ?I also don't know the test cases in which it might be failing

some of the accepted solution of other guys that seem to use the same logic and there solution is accepted [accepted sol](http://xoptutorials.com/index.php/2017/01/01/spojcrds/)

Test case:

```
      2
      3
      7
```

output:

```
      15
      77
```

.

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        while(t--){
            int n;
            cin>>n;
            unsigned long long int sum1=0;
            unsigned long long int sum2=0;
            sum1=((n*(n-1))/2)%1000007;
          //  cout<<"sum1 is"<<sum1;
            sum2=(n*n+n)%1000007;
            cout<<(sum1+sum2)%1000007<<endl;

        }

    }
```

EDIT

The answer get accepted when i use unsigned long  long n but max value of n was
1000 000 then it should also get accepted in int n because nmax is under  range of int

Comment: "#include<bits/stdc++.h>" - Don't do that. That header is for the implementation to use, *not* you.

Comment: At what size input does it start to fail? Seems like `(n*n+n)` would be the best candidate for an overflow.

Comment: A good hint is provided in the link you gave: first divide by 2 ...

Comment: This `sum1=((n*(n-1))/2)%1000007` looks dangerous when using unsigned types, if the value for `n` that is entered can be less than, or equal to, zero.

Comment: why we should divide by 2 first? @Damien

Comment: But in the question it is given that n>1 ? Then why answer is wrong @JesperJuhl

Comment: To limit the size of intermediate values. Try on a simple example

Comment: @user10891599 The question was behind an external link, so I did not read it.

Comment: Show a case in which your program get wrong results and what should be the correct one

Comment: Answer get accepted when i use unsigned long long n but max value was of n was 1000 000?
so it should also get accepted on int n also

Comment: @Damien Please note that in the linked solution the division is performed *after* the multiplication, `n * (n - 1)`, which, while a possible cause of overflow for an 32-bit `int`, has the nice property of beeing always even.

Comment: ***Answer get accepted when i use unsigned long long n but max value was of n was 1000 000? so it should also get accepted on int n also*** 1000 000 * 1000 000 is greater than 2^32. Even though sum1 is unsigned long long the inner calculation is done as int.

Comment: `n` may be in the range of an `int`, but (10^6)^2 is greater than the value of INT_MAX in most implementations. Note that the result of `((n*(n-1))/2)%1000007` is converted to the type of `sum1` only *after* having been evaluated as an `int`.

Comment: @Bob__ Right. I just read the analysis before the programme: "Be certain that you do the division first because ...". Note also that if `n` is odd, you can divide `(n-1)` by 2 instead of dividing `n`.

Comment: You made `sum1` unsigned long long but the suggestion was to make `n` unsigned long long.

Answer (score 2):

Your code overflows the range of `int` in the `n * (n - 1)` and `n * n` multiplications when `n` is large.

It has to do with the order of operations.  For instance, `(n * n + n) % 1000007;`  Here, first `n *  n` is calculated.  The result is bigger than you can fit in an `int`,  so you get integer overflow.  The resulting `int` value is smaller than it should be because of the overflow.  To that too small value, `n` is added.  This results in another `int` that is too small.  That too small value is divided by `2`.  Finally, the `%` is carried out.

A simple workaround is to declare `n` like this:

```
unsigned long long n;
```

By changing the type of `n` to `unsigned long long`, each step in the calculation will be of type `unsigned long long` since the first step of the calculation is carried out on `n`.

Comment: sorry the solution is accepted but why this happened  range was 1 000 000 only? which is under int range

Comment: @user10891599, It happens because there are interim results that exceed the range of `int`.